# Google Structured Testing Tool API

Tags: google-api

Looking for the Google Structured Testing Tool Api here: https://console.developers.google.com/ but didn't find any resource.

Does Google offer this particular api? If not how do I use this tool in web development side?

Answer (score 0):

from Google where is no Testing Tool APi for this. But you could use other APIs testing your markups:

http://json-ld.org/playground/

or use the API from Yandex:
https://tech.yandex.com/validator/